# Openfire RestAPI for PHP Configuration

Tags: php, openfire

I am trying to connect to my Openfire Server using RestAPI from [Github](https://github.com/gnello/php-openfire-restapi)

Now I have installed RestAPI plugin in Openfire folder.
I am on Centos 7.

```
    <?php

include "vendor/autoload.php";

$api = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\API();

//Set the required config parameters
$api->Settings()->setSecret("YWRtaW46YWRtaW4");
$api->Settings()->setHost("localhost");
$api->Settings()->setServerName("localhost");

//Default values
$api->Settings()->setPort("9090");
$api->Settings()->setSSL(false);
$api->Settings()->setPlugin("/plugins/restapi/v1");
```

Now WhenI try to connect it shows error:

```
if($result['response']) {
    echo $result['output'];
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

In httpd logs it says undefined $result which is obvious.

But I followed the steps as it were mentioned on its repository.

Can Any One please guide me how to use this ?

**#Udated**

```
    include "vendor/autoload.php";

$api = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\API();

//Enable debug mode
$api->Settings()->setDebug(true);
$requests = \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\Debug\Request::getRequests();

//var_dump($api);

//var_dump($requests);

$result = $api->users();
//var_dump($api);

$username ="test2";
$results = $api->getuser($username); 


 if($result['response']) 
    { 
        echo $result['output']; 
    } 
else 
    { 
        echo 'Error!'; 
    }
```

Comment: Under development you may need access to some useful information of the execution of software they're not normally available. To do this just enable debug mode like this

//Enable debug mode
$api->Settings()->setDebug(true);

Comment: i tried enabling the debug mode but no good :( it does not show anything on screen @JYoThI

Comment: you have to execute anything and then get $results like this //Add a new user
$properties = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
$result = $api->Users()->createUser('Username', 'Password', 'Full Name', 'email@domain.com', $properties); if($result['response']) {
    echo $result['output'];
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}

Comment: simple $results = $api->getuser($username); and then now check if($result['response']) {
    echo $result['output'];
} else {
    echo 'Error!';
}

Comment: $results = $api->Settings()->setPlugin("/plugins/restapi/v1"); f($result['response']) { echo $result['output']; } else { echo 'Error!'; }

Comment: @JYoThI i have updated the question please check the code there

Comment: @JYoThI it shows error

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/gnello/php-openfire-restapi

Easy Php REST API Client for the Openfire REST API Plugin which provides the ability to manage Openfire instance by sending an REST/HTTP request to the server

Please read documentation for further information on using this application.

**Installation**

```
composer require gnello/php-openfire-restapi
```

**Authentication**
There are two ways to authenticate:

**Basic HTTP Authentication**

```
$authenticationToken = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\AuthenticationToken('your_user', 'your_password');
```

**Shared secret key**

```
$authenticationToken = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\AuthenticationToken('your_secret_key');
```

**Start**

```
$api = new \Gnello\OpenFireRestAPI\API('your_host', 9090, $authenticationToken);
```

**Users**

```
//Add a new user
$properties = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
$result = $api->Users()->createUser('Username', 'Password', 'Full Name', 'email@domain.com', $properties);

//Delete a user
$result = $api->Users()->deleteUser('Username');

//Ban a user
$result = $api->Users()->lockoutUser('Username');

//Unban a user
$result = $api->Users()->unlockUser('Username');
```

**Then print Result.**

**Open Link Fore more.**
https://github.com/gnello/php-openfire-restapi